# Failed to Attach Database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I created a database using SQL Server 2008 and detached it.

When I try to re-attach on another server, I get this message:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Attach database failed for Server ' x-PC'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The database 'manage' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>   Could not open new database 'manage_test'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)

Comment: update the version of your "SQL Server Management Studio" where you are attaching. It will resolve.
http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=948

Comment: @fr34k: updating the **Management Studio** isn't going to help at all.... it's the **core engine version** that's relevant in this case - not the management tool's version ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot attach/detach or backup/restore a database from a **newer version** of SQL Server down to an **older version** - the internal file structures are just too different to support backwards compatibility.

In your case, you have a SQL Server **2008 R2** database (version 661), and you're trying to attach it to a SQL Server **2008** server (version 655). This will not work since SQL Server **2008** and **2008 R2** are *two different versions* - they are *not* compatible when going from 2008 R2 "down" to 2008.

You can either get around this problem by

- using the same version of SQL Server on all your machines - then you can easily backup/restore databases between instances
- otherwise you can create the database scripts for both structure (tables, view, stored procedures etc.) and for contents (the actual data contained in the tables) either in SQL Server Management Studio (`Tasks > Generate Scripts`) or using a third-party tool
- or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.